# MongoDB service open for only one port

Tags: mongodb

I save some content for my website saved in my MongoDB.
Currently i open my MongoDB for all ip addresses.

```
/etc/mongod.conf:  
bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

For testing it´s enough if i open the db only for my home IP.
To figure out my own IP address i did following:

```
mongod --bind_ip_all
```

> 2018-01-27T10:59:51.715+0100 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted
>   from **95.168.xxx.xx:49943** #1 (1 connection now open)

But if I use this IP on bindIP i can´t create a connection from my home device:

```
/etc/mongod.conf:  
bindIp: 95.168.xxx.xx

service mongod start
```

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [1xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017]
>   on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   1xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I get following result if i query the status:

```
service mongod status
```

> Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested
>   address

Comment: Typically there are commands to show your IP address in all OS, e.g. `ifconfig` in Linux, `ipconfig` in Windows, etc. How do you know that `95.168.xxx.xxx` is not someone else trying to connect to your server?

Comment: If your server is behind a NAT/firewall, then you would need to determine your external-facing IP address (e.g. using http://whatismyip.com/) and configure your firewall to allow access to your server. The `bindIp` setting configures the MongoDB server to bind only to the specified network interface.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha thanks for your answer. I compared this ip with ipconfig and it´s the same. On iptables i don´t deny and ip. So Mongo should bind to my ip and my server should accept this ip (otherwise i can´t connect if i bind to 0.0.0.0)

Comment: Apologies if you know this already. If you bind the server to a specific IP, you must connect to that IP. For example, if you bind to `123.123.123.123`, then you must run `mongo 123.123.123.123` to connect to it. If you bind your server to `0.0.0.0` then any IP that is associated with that machine will allow you to connect, e.g. `mongo 127.0.0.1` and `mongo 123.123.123.123` will both work.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha No issue for which you have to apologies :). I´m glad for your help anyway. That's a good point too. I added the error which i get if i request the status of mongodb. Unfortunatelly that was not the issue.

Comment: That error sounds like you have the `bind_ip` address wrong. The same error is displayed if I try to bind to an address my machine doesn't own, like `127.0.0.2`

Comment: Mhm. so i build a workaround now. I opened my mongodb for all ips but enabled only my ip from my firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file format is missing an option. If you want to bind to a specific ip, try this in your conf

```
net:
  bindIp: <your ip>
```

`bindIp` is apart of the `net` option within the configuration file. Just remember to use spaces for your indentation

And then to start, either call `service start` or to start from the cmd line use:

```
mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

However, if you want to bind to all ip addresses

```
net:
  bindIpAll: true
```

Comment: ok it looks like i do nothing wrong. i tried to start from the cams line with binding to my ip and i get following error "Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address"
do you have an idea how to fix that issue?

Comment: @nicoschuck have you tried running the command with `sudo`/as root user?

Comment: @MohammadAli i´m loged in as root :/

Comment: @nicoschuck your OP is in relation to starting mongod from a conf file. Please update your question so I can help

Comment: @N3i1 i believe 'service mongod start' starts everytime from conf file. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @nicoschuck by default yes. I was just checking! You've mentioned an issue about starting mongo this way  `mongod --bind_ip `, or maybe I've just read it wrong.